# How to check if socket.io is installed on my system

Tags: npm, socket.io

I am trying to implement chat using the following URL:

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ ...

the above website says I need to install socket.io using npm

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

But I think I have already installed socket.io on my system but I don't know how to check whether it is already or not.

I tried

```
socket.io -v
```

but it throws the following error

```
-bash : socket.io: command not found
```

Comment: Did you try `var io = require('socket.io')();` in our project?

Comment: npm packages are not bash command. For example: when I tried _mongoose -v_ I've also got _mongoose: command not found_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io has been installed on your system if the npm command runned normally.

You can try for example a file with this script in your index.html

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('/');
        socket.emit('api', {command: 'test', args: {
            text: "Hello World" 
        }}, function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        });

            socket.on('api', function(data, fn){
            if(data.command=="test"){
                window.alert (data.args.text)
            }
       });

    </script>
```